# Как привильнее сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Множествено людей проголосовал**и** за этот закон" или "проголосовал**о**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если собирательное существительное имеет при себе управляемое слово в **родительном падеже множественного числа** (в вашем случае - *людей*), то сказуемое может быть как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа. В последнее время все чаще в подобных случаях предпочтительнее согласование по смыслу (т.е. сказуемое имеет форму множественного числа): *Множество людей проголосовали за этот закон*.